# to check if a file belongs to a class in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have 5 classes,

namely:

```
earn

acq

money

fx

crude
```

I have a list of about 20000 files,
and i have a document "topics.txt", that is of the form:

```
earn~6~7~4

grain~9~1~2~12

money~4~29
```

and so on..
where the numbers correspond to the filename, and the words correspond to the classes.

i need to print all the files falling under only the  classes that i have previously mentioned,i.e; "earn","acq","money","fx" and "crude"

ex output:
(earn-6.txt,7.txt,4.txt)

(acq-5.txt)

and so on..

I am able to print for all the available classes in "topics.txt", but i want to print for only the 5 particular ones.

```
import collections
import sys
sys.stdout=open('dicti1.txt','w')
with open('topics.txt') as f:
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        value, *keys = line.strip().split('~')
        for key in filter(None, keys):
            d[key].append(value+".txt")


for i in d.items():
    print(i)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "under only the classes that i have previously mentioned"? Not print files which also have other tags?

Comment: the files under the tags:earn,acq,money,fx,crude

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood the problem, you are working to hard. Also I suggest not overwriting `sys.stdout`.

Try something like this:

```
interesting_types = ['earn', 'acq', 'money', 'fx', 'crude']
with open("in.txt") as in_file, open('out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for l in in_file:
        if l:
            type, *filenames = l.strip().split("~")
            if type in interesting_types:
                out_file.write("({}-{})\n".format(type, ",".join(["{}.txt".format(x) for x in filenames])))
```

Comment: where does it raise the value error, in the line with split("~")?

Comment: Then I guess your input file contains multiple ~ per line... can you doublecheck your stated information about your input?

Comment: yes, it does! i am sorry, it is of the form :    earn~6~7~4

    grain~9~1~2~12

    money~4~29

and so on..